# How to ensure that two columns in different tables have the same values

Tags: t-sql, constraints

What T-SQL DDL is required to create a constraint that ensures that the values in a column in one table are the same as the values in a column in a different table?

I want to do this **without using a PK-FK relationship**.
The T-SQL DDL at the end of this post is an example of the *generic problem* that I'm trying to solve.

In this example, I want to know how to add an equality constraint between the two tables that ensures that the set of values in the column:
"PersonMayDriveCar.personName" 
is always equal to the set of values in the column 
"DriverLicense.personName"

```
CREATE SCHEMA "Equality Constraint"
GO
CREATE TABLE "Equality Constraint".PersonMayDriveCar
(
    carVin nchar(4000) NOT NULL,
    personName nchar(70) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PersonMayDriveCar_PK PRIMARY KEY(personName, carVin)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE "Equality Constraint".DriverLicense
(
    driverLicenseNr int NOT NULL,
    personName nchar(70) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT DriverLicense_PK PRIMARY KEY(driverLicenseNr),
    CONSTRAINT DriverLicense_UC UNIQUE(personName)
)
GO
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189339/discussion-on-question-by-ken-evans-how-to-ensure-that-two-columns-in-different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you want to maintain referential integrity between the two tables without using a foreign key.

Based on my past experience, I solved such an issue using a trigger.
So you can create a trigger on the DriverLicense table which ensures that any insert or update into the DriverLicense table will be rolled back if the inserted driverLicenseNr doesn't exist in the PersonMayDriveCar table.

You can go through this for a full example:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4242/sql-server-referential-integrity-without-foreign-keys/

Comment: Thanks P.B.UDAY - Your suggestion seems to be exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Adhere to convention:

1. Use an FK. It’s that simple.
2. Don’t link these table together with an FK, because they are both child tables of ...
3. Create a `person` table, which is the parent of the other two tables

Try this:

```
Person
- id (PK)
- name
- other columns

PersonMayDriveCar
- person_id (FK to person)
- other columns

DriverLicense
- person_id (FK to person)
- other columns
```

Comment: ... Or change the PersonMayDriveCar to relate to the drivers licence instead of to a person - this way if a person have multiple citizenship (and a drivers license for each citizenship) than that person can drive one vehicle with one drivers license but another with the other drivers license (i.e in case that in one country the person  is authorized for driving a motorcycle but in the other their not).

Comment: Zohar and Bohemian: You are both changing the problem to fit your solution. Please see my comment in the chat section.